# How to use? iOS 11 will also allow usage of AutoLayout inside titleView

Tags: ios11

iOS 11 will also allow usage of AutoLayout inside titleView , how to use AutoLayout inside titleView?Have some examples?  Help!

Answer (score 0):

You can already use AutoLayout in custom titleView on UINavigationBar under iOS 10 include iOS 10.
Because the custom titleView is just UIView.
But, if you want to adjust AutoLayout to custom titleView, just like below.

```
UIView *customTitleView;  //Assume that is custom titleView on UINavigationItem.

if (customTitleView.superview != nil) {
    [customTitleView.superview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:customTitleView
                                                                     attribute:blahblah
                                                                     relatedBy:blahblah
                                                                        toItem:customTitleView.superview
                                                                     attribute:blahblah
                                                                    multiplier:1.0
                                                                      constant:0.0]];
}
```